# middle mouse button not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I have a Lenovo thinkpad t510, with ubuntu 15.10.
When i first installed, I was able to use the middle click mouse button to copy and paste in the terminal. This button no longer does this, or anyother function evidently. I opened up `xev` and tried clicking the middle mouse button. Nothing happened. I tried enabling and disabling the track pad. The same results.

I looked in the mouse configure section, under System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> mouse.
I saw nothing about a middle mouse button.

I really liked the middle mouse button click copy and paste, how should I go about fixing this?

I am using Ubuntu Mate 15.10.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/302077/how-to-enable-paste-in-terminal-with-middle-mouse-button

Comment: That solution does nothing for my problem.  It is a similar issue, but Im not sure that it is the same.  The Thinkpad keys are not exactly a track pad.

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful to resolve the middle mouse button and copy-paste issue:

https://askubuntu.com/a/902976/354678

Looks like Ubuntu and XUbuntu in 17.10 still have the same issue like 12.04. 
There are feasible solutions.